# How to find natural numbers $k$ and $l$ such that $481(15k + 16l) = u^2$ and $481(15k - 16l) = v^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, systems-of-equations

I have the following property $G$:

> There exist two natural numbers $(u,v)$ for which:  $$ 15a + 16b = u^2 ; 16a - 15b
>  = v^2$$ Where  $a,b \in \mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$

How to prove that If i chose $a = 481k$ and $b = 481l$ where $k$ and $l$ are natural number, then my property $G$ is true ?

In other words how do I prove that that there exist natural numbers for which :

$481(15k + 16l) = n^2$ and  $481(15k - 16l) = m^2$ where $(n,m) \in N^2$

Comment: In your first equation line you flip the $16$ and $15$ compared to the title and rest of the question.  Is this a typo?

Comment: Is $G$ supposed to be true for any $a,b?$.  It is not.  Is it supposed to be true for some $a,b,u,v$?  You can prove that by exhibiting one solution.  Please make the question clear.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes it was a typo, also $G$ is supposed to be true for some $a,b,u,v$

Comment: If $a=481k$ and $b=481l$, then the second equation $16a-15b-v^2$ becomes $481(\color{red}{16k}-15l)=v^2$. However, you wrote $481(\color{red}{15k}-16l)=m^2$. Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply first equation with 16 and second with 15 and then substract you get:

$$481b= 16u^2-15v^2 \Longrightarrow 481\mid 16u^2-15v^2\Longrightarrow 13\mid 3u^2-2v^2 $$
So we have $$3u^2\equiv _{13}2v^2  \;\;\stackrel{\cdot 7}{\Longrightarrow} \;\; 8u^2\equiv _{13}v^2$$ which means that $8$ quadratic residue modulo $13$ if $13\nmid u$. But this not the case since we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x&\equiv_{13} & 0\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm 4,\pm5,\pm 6\\ 
x^2&\equiv_{13} & 0, 1,4,-4,3,-1,-3
\end{eqnarray*} 
So $13\mid u$ and $13\mid v$. The same procedure we do for $37$.

**Edit:** So $u=481m$ and $v=481n$ and thus $$481b= 16u^2-15v^2 = 481^2(16m^2-15n^2)$$
so $$b= 481(16m^2-15n^2)$$ and the similary for $a=...$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but Unfortunately, I didn't truly understand your answer , How is this related to prove that $G$ is true for $a = 481k$ and $b = 481l$

Comment: I have made an edit